# Best way to store text, font, and color in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm working on a text editor iPhone app where a user can type and save a note with custom font, size, and color. So I have an `NSString`, `UIFont`, and a `UIColor`. I need to store all these in some sort of data structure, but I'm not sure what would be the best method. Currently I'm using an `NSMutableArray` which writes to a plist for the string, and two other `NSMutableArray` of custom objects that save to `NSUserDefaults` on exit. But this is getting way too complicated to manage and debug. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: This is how I'd save those items :) You say you're using arrays to store the font and color - surely for the font you could just save the name and just the hex code for the color? This would depend on how you currently load those and allow for selection, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a custom NSObject subclass, called AttributedText. It would store these values using custom setters and could be retrieved from the data store with custom getters too. You could easily make it save to NSUserDefaults, if you used this custom object.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is the most straightforward already. If you're looking for something a bit cleaner, you might consider building a small custom object that is responsible for:

1. Storing the data you want, and
2. Saving/loading in `NSUserDefaults` as needed

Define a simple getter/setter API on the object for the data you want, and use it to separate out the complexity of dealing with the arrays and user defaults. (You'll use most of the same implementation you already have, just in a different class.)

Comment: Would an NSDictionary be of any use here?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're trying to do. It may be easier to use an NSDictionary with keys (`text`, `font`, `color`) than a three-element NSMutableArray, if that's your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just store an attributed string.

Comment: NSAttributedString claims to conform to NSCoding on iOS, but it usually doesn't work since almost all of its attributes are non-bridged Core Text types.